# ¿Como hacer un evento al pulsar dos teclas?

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que quiero incluir atajos de teclado. El programa en cuestion tiene una serie de jTextFields que quiero ir rellenando directamente con el teclado sin tener que estar saltando de campo en campo, y ademas quiero poder hacerlo de manera que incremente los valores en 1 cada vez.

Por ejemplo, si pulso Q+1, un jtextfield aumentara su valor 1 punto, si pulso e+2, se incremente otro jtextfield un punto (las teclas que he puesto son ejemplos).

Tampoco se donde deberia poner el evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo de un textfield que solo permite números y con dos atajos de teclado:

```
    // Numeros enteros como formato
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
    formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);

    // Textfield iniciado a 0 y alineado a la derecha
    JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    textField.setValue(0);
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

    // Atajos de teclado
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {         
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // Para sumar uno
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                textField.setValue(((Integer.valueOf(textField.getText()) + 1)));

            // Para restar uno
            } else if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                textField.setValue(((Integer.valueOf(textField.getText()) - 1)));
            }           
        }
    });

    // Ventana que lo contiene
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);      
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Lo primero es crear el formato para que solo permita introducir números enteros.

Una vez creamos el textfield con la configuración que queramos. Añadimos los listener para cuando pulsen una tecla.

Tu hablabas de Q + 1 o Q - 1 pero normalmente en los atajos de teclado se usa un modificador como puede ser ctrl o shift y una tecla. En el ejemplo yo he usado ctrl q para sumar y ctrl a para restar.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.